# SharePoint 2010 Subsite Template as a Sub Sub Site

Tags: sub-site

I have a Sub Site which needs to be saved as a template but uploaded as a Sub Sub Site.  Is there an easy fix e.g,

Current setup = X1 Landing page - X 3 Sub sites (1 should have been created as a sub sub site before being developed).

Mark

Comment: Do you want to **move** your subsite to be created as subsubsite, or to **make a new** site as subsubsite which is based on the previously made subsite?

Comment: I would like to move the sub site to become a subsubsite.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement is to move a subsite to become a subsubsite, you can do this by using the **Content and Structure** tool which is built-in into the SharePoint.

To access the Content and Structure tool, at the root of your site collection navigate to **Site Settings** > See below **Site Administration** -group > **Content and Structure**.

With Content and Structure tool you can **move** a site by accessing the desired site's setting menu and selecting the move-option.

Comment: @MarkH glad to help. If this provided the answer to your question, you should mark it as the answer to promote the solution for others as well.